# Where is remainder of icon bar? I have many programs installed on 16.04 but cannot find them

Tags: boot, 16.04

Please help with locating icon bar for installed programs.  I cannot locate in help how to find installed applications other than what came with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no locating bar for installed applications. You can find them by simply this command :

```
dpkg --listfiles <package_name>
```

For example if you want the installed location for firefox use

```
dpkg --listfiles firefox
```

Comment: I need space on the left side to show all remaining programs-other than uninstalling and reinstalling which does add them to the end of the vertical bar as normal programs/ Surely Ubuntu did not forget about this  problem?